# Appropriate time to wait before asking about rep not being fully restored after a suspension

Tags: discussion, support

**Main Question**

If a user has been suspended from Stack Exchange as a whole and their rep has only been partially restored, and seemingly (from their end at least...) only on certain sites and not others, is this a normal thing and if not, what would be the appropriate waiting time before asking a question about it?

**Supplementary**

- Is the decision regarding restored reputation made by individual Stack Exchange communities, or perhaps by the Stack Exchange community as a whole?
- Are there particular levels of access enjoyed only by certain users
  or user-groups, or particular lines of appeal and escalation,
  particularly as in some circles Stack Exchange reputation may affect
  job prospects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a user got a network wide suspension (reputation on all sites drops to 1), once it has expired, the reputation will be restored on all sites.

If a user got suspended on several different sites (normally by the moderators of each site - this wouldn't normally be a coordinated thing - each site moderators would act on behalf of their site and their site alone) - in such a case, each site suspension will expire independently, according to the length of the suspension on that site.

The reputation aspect of suspensions is *automatic* - it drops to 1 while the suspension is in place and is restored once the reputation expires (you can go to the user page on any specific site to see whether a suspension is still in place there).

**No one** decides to "partially restore" reputation or not (barring reputation removed from fraudulent voting - this can be the basis of a suspension, but the reputation gained fraudulently will not be restored - the remaining, non fraudulent reputation will be restored).

In regards to appeal of suspensions - using the contact us link in the footer to get in touch with the community team (Stack Exchange employees) is the way to go. You will note I said nothing about appealing reputation - this is because there isn't anything to appeal (reputation drops to 1 during suspension period is fully restored when it is over, barring vote fraud).